# How to eliminate a path where exists a relationship outside of the path, but between nodes in the path?

Tags: neo4j

I have modified the 'vanilla' initial query in [this console](http://console.neo4j.org/?id=220r30), and added one relationship type 'LOCKED' between the 'Morpheus' and 'Cypher' nodes.

How can I modify the existing (first-run) query, which is a variable length path so that it no longer reaches the Agent Smith node due to the additional Locked relationship I've added?

First-run query:

```
MATCH (n:Crew)-[r:KNOWS|LOVES*2..4]->m
WHERE n.name='Neo'
RETURN n AS Neo,r,m
```

I have tried this kind of thing:

```
MATCH p=(n:Crew)-[r:KNOWS|LOVES*2..4]->m 
WHERE n.name='Neo'
AND none(rel IN rels(p) WHERE EXISTS (StartNode(rel)-[:LOCKED]->EndNode(rel))) 
RETURN n AS Neo,r,m
```

..but it doesn't recognize the pattern inside the none() function.

I'm using Community 2.2.1

Thanks for reading

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you can't use a function in a `MATCH`y type clause like that (though it's clever).  What about this?

```
MATCH path=(neo:Crew)-[r:KNOWS|LOVES|LOCKED*2..4]->m 
WHERE neo.name='Neo'
AND NOT('LOCKED' IN rels(path))
RETURN neo,r,m
```

EDIT:

Oops, looks like Dave might have beat me to the punch.  Here's the solution I came up with anyway ;)

```
MATCH p=(neo:Crew)-[r:KNOWS|LOVES*2..4]->m
WHERE neo.name='Neo'
WITH p, neo, m
UNWIND rels(p) AS rel
MATCH (a)-[rel]->(b)
OPTIONAL MATCH a-[locked_rel:LOCKED]->b
WITH neo, m, collect(locked_rel) AS locked_rels
WHERE none(locked_rel IN locked_rels WHERE ()-[locked_rel]->())
RETURN neo, m
```

Comment: Hrm, I'm realizing what you want is to find links that have both `KNOWS|LOVES` and a `LOCKED` and exclude those paths...  I'll re-think

Comment: If have used that function in the WHERE clause after a MATCH line, and it seems to recognize obvious patterns in it's own WHERE clause, but falls down when you try to use a 'pointer' like StartNode(rel) as I have above.

The compiler has no problem with this for example:

MATCH (n:Crew)-[r:KNOWS|LOVES*2..4]->m
WHERE n.name='Neo' AND 
NONE (rel IN r  WHERE Exists((n)-[:LOCKED]->(m)))
RETURN n AS Neo,r,m

...although, that never going to do what I want it to do.

Comment: I'm liking this solution Brian, but do I lose the original path?  I can't seem to pass it through to the end of the statement without objection.

Comment: I used this statement Brian if it's amended right, do you want to change your answer slightly?
MATCH p=(neo:Crew)-[r:KNOWS|LOVES*2..4]->m 
WHERE neo.name='Neo'
WITH p, neo, m
UNWIND rels(p) AS rel
MATCH (a)-[rel]->(b)
OPTIONAL MATCH a-[locked_rel:LOCKED]->b
WITH neo, m, collect(locked_rel) AS locked_rels
WHERE none(locked_rel IN locked_rels WHERE ()-[locked_rel]->())
RETURN neo, m

Comment: Any ideas how to retain the original path then Brian?  I tried this but it complains:

MATCH p=(neo:Crew)-[r:KNOWS|LOVES*2..4]->m 
WHERE neo.name='Neo'
WITH p, neo, m
UNWIND rels(p) AS rel
MATCH (a)-[rel]->(b)
OPTIONAL MATCH a-[locked_rel:LOCKED]->b
WITH p, neo, m, collect(locked_rel) AS locked_rels
WHERE none(locked_rel IN locked_rels WHERE ()-[locked_rel]->())
RETURN p, neo, m

Comment: Maybe put a `WITH p, neo, m` after the first `WHERE`?

Comment: It's there, but for some reason it does not like it:- Unknown identifier `r`.

Comment: I can understand why the `r` variable wouldn't work for variable paths.  You may just want to drop it since it's not used

Answer (score 2):

Ok, this is a little convoluted but i think it works.  The approach is to take all of the paths and find the last known good nodes (ones that have LOCKED relationships leaving them). Then use that node(s) as a new ending point(s) and return the paths.

```
match p=(n:Crew)-[r:KNOWS|LOVES|LOCKED*2..4]->m
where n.name='Neo'
with n, relationships(p) as rels
unwind rels as r
with n
, case 
    when type(r) = 'LOCKED' then startNode(r)
    else null
end as last_good_node
with n
, (collect( distinct last_good_node)) as last_good_nodes
unwind last_good_nodes as g
match p=n-[r:KNOWS|LOVES*]->g
return p
```

I think this would be simpler if there was a `locked: true` property on the `KNOWS` and `LOVES` relationships.

Comment: To have a property on the relationship you might be putting it on both since both can exist.  That seems a bit messy

Comment: yeah - agreed - guess it is just moving them problem

Comment: I haven't tried your answer yet Dave, and it looks like it should work for the demo graph, but when applied to perhaps a bigger graph doesn't the opportunity arise for the second MATCH to pick up a different route than the original with a node pair that has a LOCKED relationship between them?

Comment: yes - i would say that is definitely how it would work given the way it is written currently ( I was pretty focused on the sample data).  I think it would have to have a little logic added to collect only the start nodes of the first `LOCKED` relationship in a path. That way if a path in the case where the path contained multiple LOCKED relationships only the first would be used in subsequent path matching. I can give that a go later and see if I can get it sorted.

Comment: I'm just wondering if the approach of 'severing the snake at his head', whilst diabolically clever (and maybe slightly cruel), might mean you lose the potential to identify said snake.  I know I haven't stipulated as such, but if you were looking for properties on m, the last good node may not still have these same properties.

Comment: i think you could keep the original path(s) with a with statement until the end. You could then distill both the complete path (with locks) and the subset path (without locks) into collections of nodes.  You would then have both sets.